# Behavior changing when blank console.log() call inserted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

### Code

```js
var repro_bug = () => {
    var state = { x: 1, y: 1 };

    return () => {
        var toggle = () => {
            state.y = 1;

            console.log(state.x);
        };

        // console.log();

        state.x = state.y;
        state.y = 0;

        toggle();
    };
};

var run = repro_bug();
```

### Bug

If you call `run()`, it *should* always log `1`. On Chrome 91.0.4472.114 (on Chrome OS 91.13904.0), when I call `run()` ten times or so, it starts logging `0` instead.

Oddly, if you uncomment line 11, a *blank* `console.log`, it works as expected. This leads me to believe it's a bug in Chrome, potentially involving some sort of out-of-order execution. This example is the shortest I could get it, the separate `toggle` function and object for `state` (instead of two variables) are both necessary for it to behave oddly.

Note that you need to do the final `run()` manually, as shown in the screenshots below, in order to reproduce. This is likely timing related in some way.

Cannot reproduce in Node, and another person can't reproduce on Firefox.

### Screenshots

**Uncommented (expected behavior):**

[image: Uncommented: Logs 1 on 1st-11th runs]

**Commented:**

[image: Commented: Logs 1 on 1st-10th runs and 0 on 11th run]

Comment: I reproduced it myself.

Comment: Just reproduced too. Now that's funny.

Comment: Reproduced with having log output wrapped in JSON.stringify. Now trying to set up an assertion here - and yes, got an assertion failed after some persistent pressing on Enter button. :) I wonder can it be pressured into a Selenium script or something.

Comment: You should probably just submit this as a Chromium bug report. While interesting, it's not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: [Reported to Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1225799)